# camel-netty, disconnectOnNoReply issue

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I am trying to send data to Server using camel netty. If Server is not responding to the data within configured time i need to resend the message using the same connection.

To achieve this i am setting  disconnectOnNoReply as false.

But even then it is establishing new connection and re-sending the message.

My requirement is to create new connection only after specific retries.

Answer (score 0):

The netty producer uses a connection pool, so you do not have control over which connection is being used for resend. But you could attempt to set the pool size to `1` so the pool is forced to use the same channel.